# Trouble with Android AsyncTask - JavaMail

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

As the title says, I am having some multi-threaded issues.

I am using JavaMail in order to construct an e-mail app with fully supported sending/receiving e-mails.

I have a method for fetching e-mails from server, which gets started with a service every x secnds. The issue is, when I first log in with an account and start fetching e-mails from server, I can't send messages until all emails are fetched and thread is closed.

I am not well acquainted with AsyncTasks, but both of the classes (fetch and sendmail) are separately declared, so I am not sure as to why they're interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `AsyncTask`s run on a single background thread.(!!) So your send task probably gets queued up to run after all the fetches take place.

You can choose to run AsyncTasks on a threadpool using `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor`, supplying `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` as an argument. So now your send task will get queued after all the sends complete on the N available threads in the threadpool.

That being said, long-running I/O operations should probably be run on dedicated threadpool(s), not on THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, since the default thread pools are intended for use by short-running tasks. You will end up starving UI-related use of the standard thread pools if you don't. You really want dedicated pool of two or three or four threads for the receive, and probably a separate one or two or three threads for the sends.

For what it's worth, `AsyncTask` dates from the Dark Ages of Android, has suffered repeated abuse from the Android development team, and is now officially deprecated. (Hooray!) The AsyncTask's template arguments and executor syntax are just a bad idea from the start; and it's far too easy to make mistakes using it. Google now recommends you use `java.util.concurrent` instead.

ps. To be fair, AsyncTask was designed in an age when cellphones were pathetic things with 320x200 displays, one CPU, where having two whole threads was a big deal. `java.util.concurrent` is much better.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I'll look into that!